# I don't understand error of the "php pdo error handler"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update my post. and I think there's no error in my code. I have tried almost everyhing. but it's still show this error.

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\edit.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\x\edit.php(4): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM p...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\edit.php on line 4

What is the point that I'm doing wrong ?

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = $database->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=$id");
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($sql as $x) {
    $post_id = $x["id"];        
    $post_title = $x["post_title"];     
    $post_text = $x["post_text"];               
}

if (isset($_POST["update_post"])) {
    $new_post_title = $_POST["itemName"]."[UPDATED]";
    $new_post_text  = $_POST["itemInfo"];
    try {
        $u_post = $database->prepare("UPDATE post SET post_title=:p_title,post_text=:p_text WHERE id=$id");
        $u_post->execute(array(":p_title"=>$new_post_title,":p_text"=>$new_post_text));
        if ($u_post) {
            header("location:showpost.php");
        }else {
            echo "Failed";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: it means something about your SQL query is not valid (My)SQL syntax. So the SQL engine cannot understand how to execute it. Maybe show us the SQL and we can help you with that

Comment: let me add the code.

Comment: You will most likely find that `$id` has no value.

Comment: The error is with the `query` call, not the `prepare`. Also you should bind `$id`.

Comment: You need to add the SELECT code, not the UPDATE code.

Comment: Thanks. This is not the query which is throwing the error - notice the error talks about a `SELECT` not an `UPDATE`. Try to look more closely at the message you're getting. However there is a small issue with this code as well - unless it's an incomplete sample, you don't seem to have defined the variable $id in your PHP. If that's not populated then your query will be incomplete. Also you should be including it via a parameter anyway, like you do with :post_title and :post_text.

Comment: you pass the others param but don't pass $id, change to :id and pass it in the execute array

Comment: Anyhow, if you'd like help with the code which is actually throwing the error, you'd better show us that code. You've been given a line number in the error message, so it shouldn't really be too hard to find.

Comment: @user3783243 I think it's not  `query`. and `$id`  `code` also have value that I gave from previous page.

Comment: Seems like it is `PDO->query('SELECT * FROM p...')`

Comment: guys look again. I've put all the basic code.

Comment: Ok thanks again. The problem is likely that $id is not populated or has an invalid value (e.g. it's a string not an int). Again, you should be passing this as a parameter though. As it stands, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks. You already know how to use parameters, so you need to use them **every time**. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Your code should probably also check whether $id is actually populated with a valid value before even attempting to run the query.

Comment: all the same you should get into good habits. And almost certainly the problem is directly or indirectly related to the lack of parameters and/or the lack of verifying the $id variable before you run the query. There's no need to swear. We are actually trying to help you. Regardless of the parameter stuff, have you verified what is in `$id` when you're running the code? A simple  `var_dump($_GET["id"]);` will tell you. There's nothing else which could possibly be wrong with that SQL statement. And how are you executing the script? Via a GET request or via a form POSTback?

Comment: The page seems to be set up to handle both cases, but it always tries to take the variable from $_GET. A request cannot be both GET and POST at the same time. They are different HTTP methods. Maybe try `$id = $_REQUEST["id"];` instead, so that it will pick up an "id" parameter which is either on the querystring or in the POST body, depending on the type of request. And it would be wise to include an `if` statement to check that the variable contains what you expect (e.g. that it's populated and is numeric, for example) before running the query. Anyone can put random junk into the querystring